# Remove the second OS option when restarting the PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1

I used to have two hard drives running Win 7 and Win 8.1 - I formatted the drive which had Win 7 installed but whenever I restart the computer, there is still an option to select Windows 7 (it gives errors if the user choose that option).

Of curse I can go to System > Advanced system settings > startup and recovery and change the *Time to display list of operating systems* to 0 seconds.

But is there a way to actually remove it?

Comment: A way to fix that sort of problem on Windows 7 is called a "Repair Install" and is explained in the [_How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7_](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) tutorial. A similar approach might work for 8.1.

Comment: @martineau that is a grotesque solution, as it's very time consuming and utterly unnecessary, and many suggest backing up before it e.g. youtube.com/watch?v=RC_5eb9wTfk 2min into video clip the guy suggests backing up. It's a common recommendation. Do you want to suggest he do that too? A repair installation is ridiculous in this situation. A complete waste of time to do that. And that's true of XP too, the fix is less than 5min. And you're suggesting this time consuming thing. it'd work it's just unnecessarily long. At best, not a first resort.

Comment: @martineau And if that had happened in XP, would you have done BOOTCFG /REBUILD , or would you have edited boot.ini? Or would you have done a repair installation? or a backup and repair installation? I think you know what the better solution is.

Comment: @barlop: I personallu used it on XP after removing a dual booted Win7 installation because the latter replaced the bootloader. A non-technical friend used it to fix her Win7 install. I recommend it because it's an option on available with the Windows installation disc and doesn't require a Computer Science degree to use.

Comment: @martineau You're saying you did a backup and a repair installation? Or just a repair installation?   (when I used XP I found the repair installation so good I never did a backup before it, even though it is recommended practice, I can't see why it is recommended).  So don't fear admitting whether you dod A)BAckup and REpair B)Repair and no backup.  Also, as you no doubt know, computer science does not involve fixing computers. And  XP's bootcfg /rebuild or Win7's reuivalent,has a difficulty level sufficient for a "super user". And running commands can be done via just being told.

Answer (score 0):

on the comp i'm on I only have one OS, and can't elaborate much on these, but

try msconfig boot tab. i.e. start..run..msconfig then click the 'boot' tab. 
that should show you the OSs shown in the boot menu and there may be an option to delete an unwanted one

alternatively

try opening a cmd prompt as administrator and running bcdedit (if you don't open the cmd prompt as administrator it will act like bcdedit doesn't exist) and there is a delete option with that command.

Windows XP used to have boot.ini that could be edited. Windows 7 does not.

And if you were to somehow mess up, it can always be rebuilt.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/